# Batch break up after call other batch file

Tags: windows, if-statement, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

i have the problem, that my batch process breaking up each time after call a other batch file. The batch files are used to run a make process out from IBM Rhapsody. There convert the call from Rhapsody to the Visual Studio tools. So nmake will be called from the batch after make different settings.

The scripts aren’t written completely from me, I only adapt theme to run under both windows architecture versions, x86 and x64. The first script (vs2005_make.bat) will be called from Rhapsody and run to the “call” statement. The second script (Vcvars_VisualStudio2005.bat) runs to the end. But the first script isn’t resume working, at this point the process break up without a error message.

I'm not very familiar with batch files, this is the first time I make more than simple console commands in a batch file. So I hope I have given all information’s which needed, otherwise ask me.

Here the start script (vs2005_make.bat):

```
:: parameter 1 - Makefile which should be used
:: parameter 2 - The make target mark

@echo off

IF "%2"==""        set target=all
IF "%2"=="all"     set target=all
IF "%2"=="build"   set target=all
IF "%2"=="rebuild" set target=clean all
IF "%2"=="clean"   set target=clean

set RegQry="HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0"
REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt 
Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  set arch=x86
) ELSE (
  set arch=x64
)

call "%ProgramFiles%\IBM\Rhapsody752\Share\etc\Vcvars_VisualStudio2005.bat" %arch%

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  set makeflags=
  nmake /nologo /S /F %1 %target%
) 

del checkOS.txt
del StringCheck.txt

exit
```

and here the called script (Vcvars_VisualStudio2005.bat):

```
:: param 1 - Processor architecture

@echo off

ECHO param 1 = %1

IF %1==x86 (
    SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles%
) ELSE IF %1==x64 (
    SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Unknowen architectur
    EXIT /B 1
)

SET VSINSTALLDIR="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE"
SET VCINSTALLDIR="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8"
SET FrameworkDir=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework
SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727
SET FrameworkSDKDir="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0"
rem Root of Visual Studio common files.

IF %VSINSTALLDIR%=="" GOTO Usage
IF %VCINSTALLDIR%=="" SET VCINSTALLDIR=%VSINSTALLDIR%

rem
rem Root of Visual Studio ide installed files.
rem
SET DevEnvDir=%VSINSTALLDIR%

rem
rem Root of Visual C++ installed files.
rem
SET MSVCDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%\VC

SET PATH=%DevEnvDir%;%MSVCDir%\BIN;%VCINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%VCINSTALLDIR%Common7  \Tools\bin\prerelease;%VCINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools\bin;%FrameworkSDKDir%\bin;%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%PATH%;
SET INCLUDE=%MSVCDir%\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%MSVCDir%\INCLUDE;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\include\gl;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\include;%FrameworkSDKDir%\include;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=%MSVCDir%\ATLMFC\LIB;%MSVCDir%\LIB;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\lib;%FrameworkSDKDir%\lib;%LIB%

GOTO end

:Usage

ECHO. VSINSTALLDIR variable is not set. 
ECHO.
ECHO SYNTAX: %0

GOTO end

:end
```

Here the console output, what I not understand here and find very suspicious is that after the “IF %ERRORLEVEL%” Statement in the first script all will be put out regardless the echo is set to off…

```
Executing: "C:\Programme\IBM\Rhapsody752\Share\etc\vs2005_make.bat" Simulation.mak build

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
Mehr?   set arch=x86
Mehr? ) ELSE (
Mehr?   set arch=x64
Mehr? )

call "%ProgramFiles%\IBM\Rhapsody752\Share\etc\Vcvars_VisualStudio2005.bat" %arch%
:: param 1 - Processor architecture

@echo off

ECHO param 1 = %1
param 1 = x86

IF %1==x86 (
Mehr?   SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles%
Mehr? ) ELSE IF %1==x64 (
Mehr?   SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
Mehr? ) ELSE (
Mehr?   ECHO Unknowen architectur
Mehr?   EXIT /B 1
Mehr? )

SET VSINSTALLDIR="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE"
SET VCINSTALLDIR="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8"
SET FrameworkDir=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework
SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727
SET FrameworkSDKDir="%ProgrammPath%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0"
rem Root of Visual Studio common files.

IF %VSINSTALLDIR%=="" GOTO Usage
IF %VCINSTALLDIR%=="" SET VCINSTALLDIR=%VSINSTALLDIR%

rem
rem Root of Visual Studio ide installed files.
rem
SET DevEnvDir=%VSINSTALLDIR%

rem
rem Root of Visual C++ installed files.
rem
SET MSVCDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%\VC

SET PATH=%DevEnvDir%;%MSVCDir%\BIN;%VCINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%VCINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools\bin\prerelease;%VCINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools\bin;%FrameworkSDKDir%\bin;%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%PATH%;
SET INCLUDE=%MSVCDir%\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%MSVCDir%\INCLUDE;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\include\gl;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\include;%FrameworkSDKDir%\include;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=%MSVCDir%\ATLMFC\LIB;%MSVCDir%\LIB;%MSVCDir%\PlatformSDK\lib;%FrameworkSDKDir%\lib;%LIB%

GOTO end

Build Done
```

I hope someone have an idea, i work now since two days and don't find the error... thanking you in anticipation.

Note: The word “Mehr?” in the text output is german and means “more”. I don't know were it comes from and it is possible that it is a bad translation from the English output to german.

Comment: Do you start the batch from the command-line or from visual studio?

Comment: It starts from IBM Rhapsody. There is a option to generate the code and build the programm. If you don't know Rhapsody, this is an tool to develop software with UML, the source code will be auto generated from the uml diagramms.

Comment: Did you tests if `find` is batch file?

Comment: Hi, if i comment out the find all run well, of course only of an x86 system. I searched with the Windows search according an file "find.bat" on my system, but i haven't found ones or a similar. Is there an syntax error at the find command in my script?

Comment: I suppose it's the input redirect `< checkos.txt`, but you can change the line to `findstr /i "x86" checkos.txt > nul`

Comment: With this purpose the script run correct, now. Thank you very much for your help. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word 'mehr'/'more'  is from the cmd.exe, as it leave the batch context.
The question is, why it can do this?
Normally this happens in a loop starting another batch without CALL.

So my best guess is, that you have a FIND.BAT file in one of the path directories.
You could try to remark the FIND command in your batch.

You could also test `echo ### %undefined%`.
If it's still in batch context you only see the hashes, else it echos `### %undefined%`.

Then you could move the line to find the causing command.

Answer (score 2):

such constructions doesn't work because of a parsing error with parentheses in variables, avoid it:

```
IF %1==x86 (
     SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles%
) ELSE IF %1==x64 (
     SET ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
) ELSE (
     ECHO Unknowen architectur
     EXIT /B 1
)
```

use always variables in double quotes, eg.:

```
IF "%~1"=="x86" (
     SET "ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles%"
) ELSE IF "%~1"=="x64" (
     SET "ProgrammPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
) ELSE (
     ECHO Unknown architecture
     EXIT /B 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is new for me that i can use double quotes withhin the complete set assiagnment. This have solved some problems i have had at wrot well formated script code. I have a question about your example, you use "%~1" is the "~" intentional? If so what does it matter?

Comment: However the script breaks up even with the changes, so it seems like that this were not the problem.